# SAS can ranuni(0) return 0?

Tags: random, sas

Is it possible for the function ranuni(0) to return 0? I know the theoretical probability is zero, but in reality it depends on the generator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say NO. The documentation lists the range as (0,1). Note the use of () instead of [] which is the normal notation for when the end points of the interval are excluded.

The newer `RAND('uniform')` function is a better random number generator than `RANUNI()`. The documentation for that function clearly says that the range is 0 < x < 1.

Comment: I noticed this range in the documentation but technically uniform distribution on (0,1) and the one on [0,1] are the same thing (cumulative distribution functions are exactly the same).

Answer (score 2):

No, it cannot return zero (or one).

The [formula](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lefunctionsref/63354/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1fkiqt9ygapyxn1pd1w8manlpub.htm) SAS uses for calculating the next random number is:

```
SEED = mod( SEED * 397204094, 2**31-1 )
RETURN (SEED/(2**31-1))
```

Since `2**31-1` is a prime number and the new seed cannot be 2**31-1 itself (due to using the modulo operator), `mod([anything],2**31-1)` can never return 0.